# VBA - PowerPoint 2013 - Syntax ActivePresentation.CreateVideo

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I'm trying to use the function CreateVideo with PowerPoint 2013, but I don't understand which parameters I have to give.

Following the explanations of the completion I was thinking to create something like that but it seems to me I'm missing some information.

```
ActivePresentation.CreateVideo(test,True,5,720,30,85)
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint._presentation.createvideo.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)? It lists all of the parameters, their types, and a description of what they mean, as well as a code sample..

Comment: What is your problem? Does your video not created? Error message? What is the value of "test" parameter?

Comment: Why does it seem that you're missing information?  Do you get an error message?  If so, mention it.  Exactly, word for word.  But first, try it like so instead:  ActivePresentation.CreateVideo test,True,5,720,30,85    ... remove the parentheses.  I know it won't work or even compile as in your example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Test should be the name of the recorded file

Answer (score 1):

"test" needs to be a full path to the saved file

eg

ActivePresentation.CreateVideo "C:\myvid.mp4",True,5,720,30,85